# Proof for a certain binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $1\leq m\leq n$ be positive integers. I will appreciate any help proving the following identity 
$$
\sum_{k=n}^{n+m}(-1)^k\binom{k-1}{n-1}\binom{n}{k-m}=0
$$
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we  have   *[Chu-Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)* in disguise.

> We obtain for $1\leq    m\leq  n$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=n}^{n+m}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^k\binom{k-1}{n-1}\binom{n}{k-m}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{k+n}\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}\binom{n}{k+n-m}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{k+n}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\binom{n}{m-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{-n}{k}\binom{n}{m-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^n\binom{0}{m}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index to start with $k=0$.
- In (2) we apply  the binomial identity  $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ twice.
- In (3) we apply the binomial  identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4)  we finally apply the *Chu-Vandermonde* identity.

Comment: Thanks Markus! It is not so trivial.

Comment: @boaz: You're welcome.